# Obtain row value with accompanying column name from google sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets

**Set-up**

I am reading a google sheet with python. The sheet contains answers from a google form questionary.

Each row in the sheet is one participant, and all columns are the participant's answers to the questions.

---

**Problem**

I use logic in the google form which leads to a lot of empty rows – skipping sections in the google form creates empty answers in the sheet.

E.g. sheet looks like,

```
Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4
-----------------
A1 |    | A2 | A3
   | A1 |    | A2
A1 | A2 | A3 | A4
```

I do not care about the empty answers and tell Python to disregard them in the following way,

```
list(filter(None, sheet.row_values(2)))
```

where `sheet` refers to the google sheet.

The above command provides me a list of all the answers of one participant, without empty rows.

The result for the three participant looks like,

```
p1 = ['A1','A2', 'A3']
p2 = ['A1','A2']
p3 = ['A1','A2', 'A3', 'A4']
```

However, I do not know which questions the answers answer. Is there a way to command Python to disregard all empty columns for a specific row **and** yield the accompanying non-empty column names? The column names are in row `1`.

Preferably, I obtain dictionaries like,

```
p1 = {'Q1':'A1', 'Q3':'A2', 'Q4':A3}
p2 = {'Q2':'A1', 'Q4':'A2'}
p3 = {'Q1':'A1', 'Q2':'A2', 'Q3':'A3', 'Q4':'A4'}
```

How to do this?

Comment: Could you add your current code you used to get the date from Google spreadsheet ? I never used their API. It would easy to assist you if you add your code.

Comment: This page might be helpful: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values

Answer (score 0):

**You could use this way...rstrip() function**

```
df.rstrip('ipz')
```

**In Your Program**

**`**list(filter(sheet.row_values(2).rstrip(" ")))**`**

Comment: can `rstrip()` remove the spaces from `"   hello"` ? The answer is NO!  `rstrip() returns a copy of the string in which all chars have been stripped from the end of the string (default whitespace characters).`